Density of smooth functions whose derivatives have analytical/closed form expression
I was thinking about the following question the other day and thought I'd ask here to see if anyone can make it more precise and/or make any mathematical sense: What is the density (in terms of measure, category, anything you can come up with) of the set of functions in (let's say) $C^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ whose derivative has a analytic/closed form?
My guess is that the stock answer is that the term "closed form" is not precise enough for there to be any good mathematical answer to this question, but perhaps there is a way of reframing this question that I don't see.

if you only keep the analytical restriction part then they aren't dense, as its explained in the Wiki for Smoothness: Relation to analyticity. Also check the wiki for Non-analytic smooth function. Now for the closed form part, I don't know.

This answer just gives one possible interpretation of the question in the positive; if you change the interpretation/requirements you’ll obviously get different answers.
Equip the space $C(\Bbb{R})$ of continuous functions on the real line with the topologu of uniform convergence on compact sets, and let $P_{\Bbb{Q}}(\Bbb{R})$ be the set of all polynomial functions on the real line. Then, $P_{\Bbb{Q}}(\Bbb{R})$ is dense in $C(\Bbb{R})$ (a corollary of the Weierstrass approximation theorem, and the usual density of rationals in reals).
The space of polynomials surely counts as “closed form”, and the space of continuous functions is larger than smooth functions, so this is definitely one positive answer.
However if you really want to consider smooth functions, equipped woth, say, the Frechet topology of uniform convergence on compact subsets of detivatives of all orders, the this answer won’t work (nor can it be salvaged).

Hi, I have a question related to your answer: in this wiki is stated that "the analytic functions form a meagre subset of the smooth functions"... if I am not mistaken every polynomial is analytic, so If I understood your answer right, it kind of contradicts was is said in wikipedia... Is this wiki section wrong?

@Joako it doesn’t contradict Wikipedia, precisely because of my last paragraph. Notice that the notion of meagrenes depends on the topology used.
